# Can you add multiple custom domains to multiple Github repositories?

Tags: git, github, dns, github-pages

I know that you're able to create subdomains redirect to different repositories like:

```
example.com
foo.example.com
```

But are you able to do something like:

```
example.com > foobar.github.io
differentdomain.com > foobar.github.io/different-repository
```

Or have some way to have a new custom domain redirect to a specfiic repository?

Answer (score 9):

To have Github Pages at `foobar.github.io` you need a user (or "organiaztion") account at `github.com/foobar` and a repository at `github.com/foobar/foobar.github.io`.

To have Github Pages at `foobar.github.io/different-repository` you need a branch `gh-pages` at `github.com/foobar/different-repository`.

To configure `example.com` to show `foobar.github.io` you add DNS records `A` to the domain pointing to [Github Pages IP](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider) and add a file `github.com/foobar/foobar.github.io/CNAME` with content "example.com" (don't forget to add, commit and push).

To configure `differentdomain.com` to show `foobar.github.io/different-repository` you add DNS records `A` to the domain pointing to Github Pages IP and add a file `github.com/foobar/different-repository/CNAME` in `gh-pages` branch with content "differentdomain.com" (add, commit, push).